# Add scrolling effect to all anchors except of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, anchor

I have a menu which has some menu items. All of them are defined like so:

```
<li><a href="#about" target="_self" title="about">About</a></li>
```

except on of them which links to a pdf:

```
<li><a href="pdf/theDocument.pdf" target="_blank">My Pdf</a></li>
```

Now I want to add some smooth scrolling to my page when those anchores are clicked ***except*** of the one that links to the pdf. I have the following jQuery code that adds the scrolling effect but disables the opening of the pdf file in a new tab. Here is my code that implements the scrolling.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 700);
});
```

Any ideas how to add the scrolling effect for all the anchrors except of the one that links the pdf??Thanks!

Comment: You can use `if ($(this).attr("href") == "pdf/theDocument.pdf")` in click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [:not() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to select all elements except the one that has `target="_blank"` `a:not([target="_blank"])` or select all elements except the one that has [href starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) pdf `'a:not([href^="pdf"])'`

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:not([target="_blank"])', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 700);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put an id to this link and then in your code:

```
<li><a href="pdf/theDocument.pdf" id="pdfId" target="_blank">My Pdf</a>
```

and then:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){

    if (event.target.id === 'pdfId') {
       return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 700);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all the anchors that you want the smooth scrool to take place on and

```
$(document).on('click', '.classYouAdded', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 700);
});
```